# How could I put a string for the points on the x-axis?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using ChartJS v.2, and I would like to label `arrayX` by a string that will appear when the mouse will be on hover displaying the coordinates.

ArrayX being points (numbers) I should label with something.

```
 data = {
      labels: arrayX,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'ArrayY',
        data: arrayY,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1
      }]
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the title callback for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["10", "15", "30", "80", "5000", "999999"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: (a) => ('Test string: ' + a[0].label)
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: if I put semi-quote for the message it doesn't work for this part  
title: (a) => (`Test string: ${a[0].label}`)

Comment: but I have a classic way to start the code, is this:
'var myChart1 = new Chart('myChart', {
   type : 'line', etc etc '
can you please modify the start to accomplish this.

Comment: Thats because those are not semi-qoutes but instead are backticks for a string template, updated example with normal string semi-qoutes

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this way, more easy.

```
options: {
            tooltips: {
              callbacks: {
                title:function(tooltipItems, data){
                     return 'Y: ' + tooltipItems[0].xLabel;
                } 
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: This is litterly the same answer as me

Comment: @LeeLenalee but I don't know why your I couldn't run, I tried in different ways.
Sorry about that.

Comment: MB looked at first glance you only changed way function is declared but you are also using different item from the context. So its not totally the same answer